# Datepicker dialog picks wrong year

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to get Date from Datepicker, my code is below

```
dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
                gettingDate();

            }

            private void gettingDate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int   day  = dpResult.getDayOfMonth();
                int   month= dpResult.getMonth();
                int   year = dpResult.getYear();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                 formatedDate = sdf.format(new Date(year, month, day));
            //  You can parse the String back to Date object by calling

                try {
                     date = sdf.parse(formatedDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+formatedDate, 1000).show();
            }
        });
```

my toast shows date-month correctly but in year first two digits as 39 i.e like 3913,3914 etc    please help me

Comment: I had same issue. I had used `dPicker.getYear() - 1900`. Forgot why I had used like that now. Got ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 3):

you have to use this format for getting perfect and right year.

```
dpResult.getYear()-1900;
```

Comment: @user1237894 no problem...wc

Answer (score 2):

use `dpResult.getYear()-1900`

```
int   year = dpResult.getYear();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @silverback thanks for comment ! i will surely take care from next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Date is deprecated, you should use Calendar instead with the following syntax

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.set(dpResult.getYear(), dpResult.getMonth()-1,getDayOfMonth())
```